# How to escape single quote in URL

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I m having below scenario :

I got Details as below which comes from session.

Detail=D'AXYZ;

I need to pass Detail in a java script function like below.

')"

we are just creating a dynamic url based upon the details get from  the session.
and we get below details which is passed in function:

My Javascript function is as below:

myFunction(url) {

submit(url);
}

The problem is due to extra '(single quotes) in Details filed the url is getting closed in between and so its not working.
Please advice.

Comment: Escape it with a `\\`

Comment: JavaScript string escape for single quote: `\'`

Comment: This looks like a parameter to an url that will be called eventually, so _URL_ - encode it